# Youtube share with other networks - native or webview?

Tags: android, youtube

Is there an easy way to tell whether Youtube share pop-over as shown in the image below is a custom Google's Android native share activity OR a share pop-overfrom the webview?

Can someone point me to a resourceful information regarding such share activities from different apps?

What about similar from Facebook, Uber, etc. - native or web?

[image]

Note:

1. There is a horizontal bar in the share list separating some selected and other networks.
2. The share list can be dragged to cover full screen etc. - it looks like a significant difference from the Android's native share.

Answer (score 0):

They are native implementations. Most, if not all apps will use a native implementation. Here is the developer docs.

[Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

[Adding an Easy Share Action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)

Its done by passing intents.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

There is a library that has this kind of functionality that you are looking at. You can look at it to get an idea of how it would be implemented.

https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

Comment: Thanks. Primary question - is Youtube's share pop-over native (written in java for android) or webview (comes with the hybrid page)?

Comment: They are native implementations.

Comment: How to tell if they are native or not? This will be helpful information for me in future.

Comment: There are a few ways, the feedback from the views is native for one, another is if you disable your network connection, the view is still fully functionally is another way I can tell